# Rotate objects with touch in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to rotate an object with touch in unity. I touch is moved left object should rotate leftward as long as user holds the touch and vice versa.
My code rotates the object correctly as long as touch is moved leftward or rightward. Later if touch movement is stopped and hold, object starts rotating rightward. Here is what i have tried.

```
{
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            oldTouchPosition = touch.position;
        }
        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            if (touch.deltaPosition.x > 10f)
            {
                rotateLeftward = false;
                rotateRightward = true;
            }

            else if (touch.deltaPosition.x < 10f)
            {
                rotateRightward = false;
                rotateLeftward = true;
            }
        }



        if(rotateLeftward == true )
        {
            RotateLeftWard();
        }
        else if (rotateRightward == true)
        {
            RotateRightWard();
        }
    }
}


void RotateLeftWard()
{
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 1 * keepRotateSpeed, 0f) * transform.rotation;
}

void RotateRightWard()
{
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, -1 * keepRotateSpeed, 0f) * transform.rotation;
}
```

Comment: You should rather directly use the moved deltaPosition for rotate or use `Transform.Rotate`,  with a `Time.deltaTime` .. currently you simply rotate every frame about a fixed amount but only if you loved fast enough ....

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no code that sets the both rotations to false..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to code a perfect solution for all this using the code below
I hope it will be useful

```
private Touch touch;
private Vector2 oldTouchPosition;
private Vector2 NewTouchPosition; 
[SerializeField]
private float keepRotateSpeed = 10f;

private void Update()
{
     RotateThings(); 
}
private void RotateThings()
{
  if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            oldTouchPosition = touch.position;
        }

        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            NewTouchPosition = touch.position;
        }

        Vector2 rotDirection = oldTouchPosition - NewTouchPosition;
        Debug.Log(rotDirection);
        if (rotDirection.x < 0 )
        {
            RotateRight();
        }

        else if (rotDirection.x > 0 )
        {
            RotateLeft();
        }
    }
}

void RotateLeft()
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 1.5f * keepRotateSpeed, 0f) * transform.rotation;
    }

void RotateRight()
{
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, -1.5f * keepRotateSpeed, 0f) * transform.rotation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as Gurbrinder Singh posted, but a bit advanced with a deltaThreshold

```
private Touch touch;
private Vector2 oldTouchPosition;
private Vector2 NewTouchPosition;
[SerializeField]
private float keepRotateSpeed = 10f;

[SerializeField]
private float deltaThreshold = 5f;


private void Update()
{
    RotateThings();
}
private void RotateThings()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            oldTouchPosition = touch.position;
            NewTouchPosition = touch.position;
        }

        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            oldTouchPosition = NewTouchPosition;
            NewTouchPosition = touch.position;
        }

        float delta = Mathf.Abs(oldTouchPosition.x - NewTouchPosition.x);
        if (/*touch.phase != TouchPhase.Stationary &&*/ delta >= deltaThreshold)
        {
            Vector2 rotDirection = oldTouchPosition - NewTouchPosition;
            Debug.Log(delta);
            if (rotDirection.x < 0)
            {
                RotateRight();
            }

            else if (rotDirection.x > 0)
            {
                RotateLeft();
            }
        }
    }
}

void RotateLeft()
{
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 1.5f * keepRotateSpeed, 0f) * transform.rotation;
}

void RotateRight()
{
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, -1.5f * keepRotateSpeed, 0f) * transform.rotation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work if you want a little more control

```
private float _lastTouchRot = float.NegativeInfinity;

...

private void UpdateMobile()
{
    if (UnityEngine.Input.touchCount == 2)
    {
        var touch0 = Input.GetTouch(0);
        var touch1 = Input.GetTouch(1);

        var touchRot = Vector2.SignedAngle(touch0.position - touch1.position, Vector2.right);
        if(this._lastTouchRot == float.NegativeInfinity) this._lastTouchRot = touchRot;

        var delta = this._lastTouchRot - touchRot;

        this._angle += delta;

        this._lastTouchRot = touchRot;

        if(touch0.phase == TouchPhase.Ended || touch1.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            this._lastTouchRot = float.NegativeInfinity;
    }
}
```